# Exporting list to .csv [Scala]

Tags: scala, list, export-to-csv

I am new to Scala and programming in general.
How would I go to write a list into a .csv file using Scala?

So I have a list of objects...

```
List[test] = List(test(Group1,lol,1,2,3),test(Group2,lel,4,5,6)....)
```

how would I export it to a .csv with 4 columns, and each line having the attributes of an object?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Because of so many issues, even in the presence of an RFC for the .csv MIME-type, I strongly suggest you use a well-maintained RFC driven native Scala library which optimally handles this problem, kantan.csv: https://nrinaudo.github.io/kantan.csv

Answer (score 2):

Case classes are instances of `Product` that offers a nice way to iterate through all of the fields as `.productIterator`.

The idea is that you convert all fields to strings, then escape backslashes and double-quotes if there are any, then join them all together, double-quoted and separated by commas, and then glue everything with a new-line:

```
list
 .map { 
    _.productIterator
     .map(_.toString)
     .map(_.replaceAll("\\", "\\\\"))
     .map(_.replaceAll("\"", "\\\""))
     .mkString("\"", "\",\"", "\"")
 }.mkString("\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using an existing library: https://github.com/melrief/PureCSV
Use SBT for resolving the dependency: http://www.scala-sbt.org/
Files:
* `./build.sbt`
* `./OutputCsv.scala`

`build.sbt`

```
name := "parse-csv"
version := "1.0.0"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.github.melrief" %% "purecsv" % "0.1.1")
```

`OutputCsv.scala`

```
import purecsv.safe._

object OutputCsv extends App {
    case class Test(group: String, message: String, age: Int)
    val tests = List(Test("Group1", "lol", 1), Test("Group2", "lel", 4))

    println(tests.toCSV()) // just for debug purposes
    tests.writeCSVToFileName("/tmp/example.csv", header=Some(Seq("group", "message", "age")))
}
```

`sbt run` will execute the file

Comment: That is great feedback! I have managed everything you mention except the `sbt run` part. I am using IntelliJ here and when running the code I only get `import purecsv.safe._`  `defined module OutputCsv`
So I suppose it does not run